# laravel error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher::driver()

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test my laravel application, run phpunit, but get an error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher::driver()
```

laravel 5.5, PHPUnit 7.0

My UserTest:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\User;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
   use RefreshDatabase;

   /** @test */
   function name_should_not_be_too_long()
   {
      $response = $this->post('/users', [
          'name' => str_repeat('a', 51),
          'email' => $this->user->email,
          'password' => 'secret',
      ]);

      $response->assertStatus(302);
      $response->assertSessionHasErrors([
          'name' => 'The name may not be greater than 50 characters.'
      ]);
  }
```

}

Comment: Show code as well

Comment: Make sure you have run `composer update`?

Comment: I've tried  composer update but the error remains

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your CreatesApplication class change this line:

```
Hash::driver('bcrypt')->setRounds(4);
```

To this:

```
Hash::setRounds(4);
```

After that, do a `composer dumpautoload`

If still no luck, downgrade to phpunit 6.0.

Comment: Thanks @Gazben! 
It helps (without downgrade to phpunit 6.0)